# Pycharm is not showing any output my code is below

Tags: python, json, python-requests

```
import requests
import json

url = "https://www.nseindia.com/api/option-chain-indices?symbol=NIFTY"


def fetch_data():
    global url
    req = requests.get(url).json()
    print(req)

    with open("oidata.json", "w") as files:
        files.write(json.dumps(req, indent=4, sort_keys=True))


def main():
    fetch_data()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add 'User-Agent' to headers while getting url:

```
headers={
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.87 Safari/537.36'}
```

so, fetch_date() method looks like that:

```
def fetch_data():
    global url
    req = requests.get(url, headers={
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.87 Safari/537.36'}).json()
    print(req)
    return req
```

so your code looks like that:

```
import json

import requests

url = "https://www.nseindia.com/api/option-chain-indices?symbol=NIFTY"


def fetch_data():
    global url
    req = requests.get(url, headers={
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.87 Safari/537.36'}).json()
    print(req)
    return req


def write_function(req):
    with open("oidata.json", "w") as files:
        files.write(json.dumps(req, indent=4, sort_keys=True))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    write_function(fetch_data())
```

Comment: It doesn't work with a user agent either. I just tried my own version with my computer's user agent. The JSON is displayed in the browser but the `requests` library can't get the JSON.

Comment: @Pyzard I just called fetch_date() and it prints me smth like that:{'records': {'expiryDates': ['25-Mar-2021', '01-Apr-2021', '08-Apr-2021', '15-Apr-2021', '22-Apr-2021', '29-Apr-2021', '06-May-2021', '12-May-2021',

Comment: of course if you need to reuse it's data, you should return the value from the funciton, coz it's using local variable, what is invisible out of function scope. check the code, I have updated

Comment: @Pyzard try to run last code version, what I've added, works perfectly, created file with json from the respone